# Cannot Activate Arc-Dark theme on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome3, theme

I have followed all the instructions on the [Github page](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) for the `Arc-Dark` theme in the process of creating a custom desktop, but I still cannot activate the theme.

I have installed all the dependencies and set the proper options in the `gnome-tweak-tool`. I have restarted my machine as suggested, but none of my changes take effect. What am I missing in order to install this theme?

Edit: My original install was Lubuntu, and then I installed `GNOME` and then `XFCE`. From there, I created a new desktop environment by creating `/usr/local/bin/custom_desktop`:

```
#!/bin/sh
plank &
pcmanfm &
hsetroot -full ~/Pictures/temp_background.jpg
netwmpager &
i3
```

I also created `/usr/share/xsessions/custom_desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=CustomDesktop
Comment=Custom Desktop
Exec=/usr/local/bin/custom_desktop
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/custom_desktop
Type=XSession
```

Answer (score 0):

To activate the theme, install *unity tweak tool* with this command : `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`. Now open unity tweak tool and you'll find your theme in the theme section. Just click on it and it will be activated (I just tested it on my computer).

All the themes you install can be **activated** with unity tweak tool.

Comment: I tried to install the `unity-tweak-tool`, but it keeps on complaining about not having `com.canonical.desktop.interface`. I also updated the question a little bit about my setup. I never had a Unity DE on my system before.